# case sensitive query with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I need to make some queries case sensitive to a mysql db with sqlalchemy
how can I  make a query case sensitive with sqlalchemy.
thanks in advance.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/sqlalchemy/OyUwclkPzxE

Answer (score 3):

You would need to specify that the collation on the column(s) be case-sensitive.
SQLAlchemy's support of the MySQL dialect [allows several column-types to accept a `collation` kwarg](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mysql.html).
Below is an example of how to specify a column's collation when creating a table.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
sa.__version__
# -> '0.7.7'
engine = sa.create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://uname:pword@localhost/your_db', 
                          pool_recycle=3600)
metadata = sa.MetaData()
some_table = sa.Table('some_table', metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
    sa.Column('some_column', 
              # specify case-sensitive collation
              sa.dialects.mysql.VARCHAR(100, collation='utf8_bin')), 
)
metadata.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) 
                VALUES (%s);''', ('foo',))
conn.execute('''INSERT INTO some_table (some_column) 
                VALUES (%s);''', ('FOO',))
conn.execute('SELECT * FROM some_table;').fetchall()
# -> [(1L, 'foo'), (2L, 'FOO')]
conn.execute('''SELECT * 
                FROM some_table 
                WHERE some_column LIKE %s;''', ('foo%',)).fetchall()
# -> [(1L, 'foo')]
conn.execute('''SELECT * 
                FROM some_table 
                WHERE some_column LIKE %s;''', ('FOO%',)).fetchall()
# -> [(2L, 'FOO')]
```